# Transferring data between a QNAP and Synology NAS over distance

Tags: network-attached-storage, synology, qnap

I have two NAS devices, one from Qnap, one from Synology, each in a different city and need to transfer tens of GB between them. The Synology is accessible through QuickConnect and the Qnap through myQNAPcloud and has their DDNS turned on.

I know it is possible to use rsync to transfer data between NASes of different brands, for example as discussed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/112453/copying-directories-with-subdirectories-from-qnap-nas-to-synology-nas). However, I do not know how to proceed when the devices are not in a shared network.

Could someone more experienced in this please turn me in the right direction? I have no idea how to make this work. This is a one-off task - I do not need to setup a long-term connection, I just need to transfer the data from the Qnap to the Synology.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to involve a 3rd party service, like cloud storage, you must setup a VPN tunnel between your NAS devices.

Both of them support OpenVPN (and PPTP, but OpenVPN are superior to that) server and client mode. But for the server mode to work, your Internet connection must include a valid Internet IP, i.e. not being behind ISP NAT. So you must check this first. Does your NAS are directly attached to the ISP Internet cable or they are behind a router? If they are behind the router, check what IP are assigned to you by the ISP. If it's not the part of [private IP address ranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) then chances you are NOT behind the NAT are high. Check both sides.

If one of your NASes aren't behind the NAT - you can setup an OpenVPN server there. Add other side as client. Now you are having a virtual private network between them and you can proceed with using `rsync` just like they are in the same LAN.

Comment: PPTP is just a tunnel without encryption - *no* VPN.

Comment: @Zac67 Microsoft implementation includes MPPE for encryption (yet, very insecure nowadays, that's why I've said OpenVPN are superior to that). Besides term VPN doesn't implies encryption. From the Wikipedia: "*Encryption is common, although not an inherent part of a VPN connection.*"

Comment: That encryption is so poor that you can regard it as transparent... Formally you're correct, but common perception of the term "VPN" is that it is secure and private (=unreadable to third parties), so we should explicitly point that out.

Comment: @Zac67 afair rsnyc for those NASes uses ssh as the underlying protocol, i.e. it's rsync over ssh. So the actual transfer must be secure anyways if we stick to the question as it was noted it's a "one-shot" transfer.

Comment: Yes, I agree absolutely!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My (source, or "copying from" NAS) is indeed behind a NAT. The ISP has opened port 873 for me and has given me a static IP. However, after trying tnc  -port 873 on my public IP that I got from whatismyip.com, I still can't get an answer from the port. I do get an answer when I try the tnc on my WAN IP, and I can confirm that the service on the NAS on port 873 is running.

Comment: I have edited the question to also include a tracert output. The IP in row 2 is the WAN IP of my router. The IP in row 5 is what I see as my public IP.

Comment: @Ondrej I don't see any edits to a question. Yet most likely your NAS runs rsync server over SSH port 22, not raw port 873 which is insecure.

Comment: It seems that my edits are pending review. Anyway, I tried adding a port 22 forward on my router. Same as before - trying it on my WAN IP works, but trying it on my public IP does not.

Comment: @Ondrej did your ISP opened port 22 for you as well?

Comment: Yes, they did open 22 as well.